# deploy nodejs app with aws beanstalk with code pipeline git

Tags: node.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I guess the issue is that I'm using nodejs v 16.13.0 and in beanstalk I found just nodev14
if is it true how I can upgrade the nodejs of my instance

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Elastic beanstalk (and AWS Lambda) only supports up to node 14.18.2. You will have to move to EC2 where you can install your own Node versions.

EDIT: AWS Lambda now supports Node 16.

Comment: thanks for the answer I tried to connect to the ec2 instances created by beanstalk to update the nodejs from 14 to 16 by typing :                                                                                      sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable but doesn't work